# Hibernate @Formula doesn't include Schema

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have an entity with a property **@Formula** like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "areasAuxiliar")
public final class AreaAuxiliar implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idArea")
    private Integer idArea;

    @Formula("RUTAAREA(idArea)")
    private String ruta;
```

when I configure my hibernate to point to an Oracle DB I have no problem,
BUT, when I switch to an SQLServer, hibernate is not including the *shema* and the query fails,

the query generated for hibernate looks like this:

```
select
    areaauxili4_.idArea as idArea1_6_4_,
    rutaArea(areaauxili4_.idArea) as formula2_4_
from
    SIGAP.areasAuxiliar areaauxili4_
```

the param *hibernate.default_schema=SIGAP* is being read and included in the table but not in the function,

is there an option/annotation to force the shema in in that function?

I have tried hibernate 5.1 and 5.2 with the same result :(

Comment: what function are u referring to here ?

Comment: AFAIK, the content of `@Formula.value` is passed verbatim to the query. Either create a global alias for `RUTAAREA` (not sure if SQLServer supports such aliasing, though) or prepend `RUTAAREA` with the schema name

Comment: @crizzis i cant add the schema in the code, b'cos it can change i cant build custom deploys for each case, I'm not sure but he alias can be created for tables not functions :(

Comment: @crizzis i added an alias for the function to the dbo but it's the same, the query ended like this: select dbo.RUTAAREA(idarea) from sigap.areasAuxiliar; and it is not recognised without the "dbo."

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635745/hibernate-formula-set-value-at-runtime

Comment: Also, to create a global function, try looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727925/can-i-create-create-a-global-function-in-sql-server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**a more simplified solution:**

change your @Formula from this:

```
@Formula("RUTAAREA(idArea)")
```

to this:

```
@Formula("{MYAPP_SCHEMA}.RUTAAREA(idArea)")
```

create a class:

```
public class HibernateEntityInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

}
```

register it as an Entity Interceptor in your sessionFactory, in my case:

```
sessionFactory.setEntityInterceptor(new HibernateEntityInterceptor());
```

then in that class you override this method:

```
public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
```

that method recive the sql command before it is executed, so, all you need to do is a simple replace all:

```
sql = sql.replaceAll("\\{MYAPP_SCHEMA}", default_schema);
return sql;
```

thanx for the help.

Comment: @Dan don't get me wrong, it is pretty much your answer but i try to make it more clear, and only replacing the keyword for the schema, not the schema+function, so this can work with NamedNativeQuery as well

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `mysql-orm.xml` file to override your formula then configure your build to tale into account the file when the database is mysql.

Overriding here the formula :

```
<entity-mappings
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <package>com.acme.persistence</package>
    <entity class="AreaAuxiliar" access="FIELD">
        <attributes>
            <property name="ruta" formula="schemaName.RUTAAREA(idarea)"/>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

Then add the reference in a specific `persistence.xml`. You then override your default persistence.xml with this one in your build or at runtime (cf. links below).

```
<persistence
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit">

    <provider>
        org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    </provider>

    <mapping-file>
        mappings/identifier/global/mysql-orm.xml
    </mapping-file>

    <class>
        com.acme.persistence.AreaAuxiliar 
    </class>

</persistence-unit>
```

Note : heavlily inspired from 
[How to change Hibernate GenerationType identifier depending on the underlying database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50894094/how-to-change-hibernate-generationtype-identifier-depending-on-the-underlying-da)

Note (2) : In the [blog post](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-replace-the-table-identifier-generator-with-either-sequence-or-identity-in-a-portable-way/) and [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-bootstrap-hibernate-without-the-persistence-xml-file/), the author generate the PersistenceUnitInfo at run-time.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this helps apply to the function, but have you tried adding the property 'schema' to the `@Table` annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "areasAuxiliar", schema="mySchemaName")
public final class AreaAuxiliar implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idArea")
    private Integer idArea;

    @Formula("RUTAAREA(idArea)")
    private String ruta;
```

Another solution, which was converted to a comment, is to use a place holder in the `@Formula` annotation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "areasAuxiliar")
public final class AreaAuxiliar implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idArea")
    private Integer idArea;

    @Formula("{SCHEMA_AND_FUNCTION}")
    private String ruta;
```

Then Add an Interceptor to populate the formula's value.  The link to the solution is [Hibernate @Formula set value at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635745/hibernate-formula-set-value-at-runtime)

Lastly, please see my comment about creating a global function in SQLSERVER.  The details can be found here [Can I create create a global function in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727925/can-i-create-create-a-global-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

1) I know that for *native* queries, you can use the "{h-schema}" placeholder (which will populated with the value of the "hibernate.default_schema" param):

```
"SELECT x FROM {h-schema}tableName"
```

Give a try and see if by chance this is also working in @Formula...

2) If not, you might also try to play with substitutions (i.e hibernate.query.substitutions) in order to tell hibernate to replace literal S with S' - in your case "RUTAAREA" with "schema.RUTAAREA" ?

Comment: Did you try the 2nd workaround (with substitutions) ?